# Creating a BAT file for loop running python script through whole folder

Tags: python, batch-file, for-loop

The thing is right now I have a visualization python script. If I run it on CUDA mode, I always get the error message of: `RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory`(on both CUDA mode for single image visualization and folder visualization). However, when I run the script on CPU mode, my CPU stands and it takes like 30seconds to run through one image visualization.

But when I try to have a for loop inside the python script to run the visualization through a whole dataset (about 500 images), my computer crashed at the 5th image(I suspect maybe there are some variables I didn't release after each for loop, I spent time on this approach, didn't work well).

Therefore I decide to discard the gracefulness of python code and figure if I could write a BAT file that runs my visualization script one image at a time and then go to another image till it loops through the whole dataset?

Right now I have the bash command works for a single image:

```
@echo off
python main_single_img.py -i "./data/sample_folder_0/image0.jpg" --no-cuda %*
pause
```

I'm completely new to shell code, no idea how to run through all .jpg files in this "./data/sample_folder_0/" directory. Need help!

Comment: Do you get "the CUDA error" quoted on the first image, or on the 5th just as the (program? computer?!) crash in CPU mode? (Please update your question rather than comment comments asking for additional information or clarification.)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I just solved this problem myself. But thank you guys anyway. Hope someone else with the same situation I encountered could see this post and save their time!

```
@echo off
for %%f in (./data/sample_folder_0/*.jpg) do (
    echo %%~nf
    python main_single_img.py -i ./data/sample_folder_0/%%f --no-cuda %*
)
pause
```

Comment: I can't believe this really works; in the `python` commad line, either remove the path and just write `%%f`, or if you want to keep the path use `%%~nxf`; otherwise the resulting path will probably be something like `.\data\sample_folder_0\.\data\sample_folder_0\*.jpg`. And use the `\ `as path separator in `cmd`, not the `/`!

Comment: At first, I didn't have the path in the python command line. Since all those images are actually in the subdirectory of where the BAT file is, the direct error came to me was "there is no such file in directory" when the python is trying to locate images. Thank you so much for your answer! I'd definitely try the second one next time!